# How to remove exif tags using Android ExifInterface

Tags: java, android, exif

Currently I'm working on Android application which has a function to remove EXIF tags.
Built-in Android library (android.media.ExifInterface) doesn't allow to do it. It's only possible to edit existing values. That's why I thought I can overwrite them with some empty values like empty string, space, zero. Tags in EXIF specification have different types  and I can't overwrite them with the same value.

See:
http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html

After some testing I replaced data with empty values provided below (in format they were displayed at the beginning). In comments I specified types of corresponding tags.

```
private static final Map<String, String> emptyValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
static {
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_APERTURE, "0"); //rational64u
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, ""); //string
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME, "0.0000" ); //rational64u
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH, "0" ); //int16u
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH, " 0/0" ); //rational64u
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE, "0/0" ); //rational64u
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF, "0" ); //string[2]
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, "0/0,0/0000,00000000/00000" ); // rational64u
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "0" ); //string[2]
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, "0/0,0/0,000000/00000 " ); //rational64u
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "0" ); //sting[2]
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP, "0:0:0 " ); //rational64u[3]
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD, "0" ); //undef
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP, " " ); //string[11]
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH, "0" ); //int32u
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH, "0" ); //int32u
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_ISO, " " ); //int16u
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE, " " ); //string
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL, " " ); //string
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE, " " ); //string
    emptyValues.put(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, " " ); // int16u
}
```

Is it a good approach? Is there a smarter way?

Comment: how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to just load your image into an Android Bitmap and then save the Bitmap to a new file? Bitmap objects don't store EXIF data, so this would remove the EXIF data. The downside of this method is of course that you'd have to compress it again and you might lose a little bit of image quality.

Comment: this also has the problem of ram limits for hires images